# org-mode: List everything except certain tags in custom agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

[This](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) documentation explains how to set up custom agenda views, and I understand the example code I've seen there. But there is one thing I'd like to do that might not be possible: I'd like to look over my next actions by category instead of looking through all of them at once. However, to do this I need a "miscellaneous" category to make sure I don't lose anything. This category would include all TODOs that are *not* tagged with `OFFICE`, `ERRANDS`, or `HOME`:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("O" tags-todo "OFFICE") 
        ("B" tags-todo "ERRANDS")       
        ("H" tags-todo "HOME") 
        ; Here comes the part where I make up pseudocode to show that
        ; I want a list of all TODOs that do not contain any of the
        ; tags specified above:
        ; ("M" tags-todo-NOT "OFFICE" "ERRANDS" "HOME")
        ))
```

Is this possible using Elisp?

Comment: By the way: Welcome to Emacs.SE! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("O" tags-todo "OFFICE") 
        ("B" tags-todo "ERRANDS")   
        ("H" tags-todo "HOME") 
        ("M" tags-todo "-OFFICE-ERRANDS-HOME")))
```

There's two things at work here:

1. `-` negates a search term. For example, `-OFFICE` matches headlines that are *not* tagged with `:OFFICE:`.
2. Search terms can be concatenated with `+` or `-`. A `+` in front of a tag means that headlines matching a query must include that tag.

Comment: Nice! Seems to be working perfectly. :)

Comment: You can also search for or negate regular expressions with `{...}`.  For example `"-{OFFICE\\|ERRANDS\\|HOME}"` will include everything except those tagged with one of `OFFICE`, `ERRANDS` or `HOME`.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious: Are these (isjeyds and eriks examples) features or a typical pattern of elisp *in general* or specific to orgmode?

Comment: The "+/-" syntax for including/excluding things is an orgmode thing as is the "{}" syntax for regular expressions.  The regex inside the "{}" is a standard Emacs regex.