# How to exclude several tags from view blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

I'm building my composite agenda view in org-mode. I want to exclude some entries shown in the lower block from the upper block since they are redundant.

This is what I got:

```
(setf org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("a" "Agenda"
           ((tags "PRIORITY=\"A\""
                  ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo 'done))
                   (org-agenda-overriding-header "Tareas de alta prioridad por terminar:")))
            (agenda ""
                    ((org-agenda-span 'day)
                     (tags-todo "-cumpleaños|-aniversario|-santoral")
                     (org-agenda-overriding-header "Para hoy:")))
            (agenda ""
                    ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                     (tags-todo "-cita|-evento")
                     (org-agenda-files '("~/org/fechas.org"))
                     (org-agenda-overriding-header "Cumpleaños, aniversarios y santoral:")))
            (alltodo ""
                     ((org-agenda-skip-function
                       '(or (air-org-skip-subtree-if-habit)
                           (air-org-skip-subtree-if-priority ?A)
                           (org-agenda-skip-if nil '(scheduled deadline))))
                      (org-agenda-overriding-header "Todas las tareas de prioridad normal:")))))))
```

And this is how it looks:

```
Tareas de alta prioridad por terminar:

=========================================================================================================================================================
Para hoy:
Saturday    4 February 2017
  cosas por hacer:Sched. 8x:  POR-HACER Revisar el backlog          :repetitivo:
  fechas:     Scheduled:  POR-HACER Prueba de evento                    :evento:
  fechas:     Scheduled:  POR-HACER cumpleaños de prueba            :cumpleaños:
  cosas por hacer:66 d. ago:  POR-HACER Pagar deuda con Kolbi por factura atrazada :factura:

=========================================================================================================================================================
Cumpleaños, aniversarios y santoral:
Monday     30 January 2017 W05
Tuesday    31 January 2017
Wednesday   1 February 2017
Thursday    2 February 2017
Friday      3 February 2017
Saturday    4 February 2017
  fechas:     Scheduled:  POR-HACER Prueba de evento                    :evento:
  fechas:     Scheduled:  POR-HACER cumpleaños de prueba            :cumpleaños:
Sunday      5 February 2017

=========================================================================================================================================================
Todas las tareas de prioridad normal:
  cosas por hacer:POR-HACER Comprar alguno de estos 3 cursos sobre freelancing en Udemy
```

Somehow I cannot filter things tagged as `evento` from the block called `Cumpleaños, aniversarios y santoral:` and the same for things tagged `cumpleaños` from the `Para hoy:` block.

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Also, is there a way to hide empty days in a week?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10576/11315), you can simply concatenate the tags to exclude.

So, rather than doing:

```
(tags-todo "-cumpleaños|-aniversario|-santoral")
```

Change to

```
(tags-todo "-cumpleaños-aniversario-santoral")
```